# Python - Is it possible to wait_for one event or another in Discord.py-v1.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Is there any to use `wait_for` in such a way that it will wait for either `reaction_add` or `reaction_remove`?

I've seen that there are `on_reaction_add` and `on_reaction_remove` functions, but I would like a way to do it without those.

I want something like this:

```
reaction,user=await bot.wait_for('reaction_add/reaction_remove',check=check)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this looks to be using `asyncio` facilities, use the built-ins. Just create a task for each, then use [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) to wait for the first one to fire:

```
pending_tasks = [bot.wait_for('reaction_add',check=check),
                 bot.wait_for('reaction_remove',check=check)]
done_tasks, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

When one of the tasks completes, this will return, and the task which was satisfied will appear in the `done_tasks` set. If you're no longer interested in other tasks once one of them completes, you can go ahead and cancel the others, e.g.:

```
for task in pending_tasks:
    task.cancel()
```

Comment: How do I get the `reaction` and `user` variables from the task?

Comment: @ProfessorDragon: The object(s) in `done_tasks` are normal awaitables, you just happen to know `await`ing them won't block; you can just do `for task in done_tasks: reaction, user = await task`.

Comment: Also, do you know of a way to see which event happened? (For example, tell if it was a reaction added or removed...)

Comment: @ProfessorDragon: There's an example (with a warning on making sure the types are already tasks when passed in) on doing exactly that in the docs I linked.